# Reading/downloading attachment from Email using groovy

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to download outlook email attachments using Groovy or count how many attachments are there in the email? I'm trying to write a code where I can use the no. of attachments further. I've seen examples for downlaodin content from url but not from Emails.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to download outlook email attachments using Groovy or
> count how many attachments are there in the email?

It is.  There are many many libraries to help you do that.

The particulars of how to do it depend on knowing more about your application.  For example, if you are doing this in a web application that is built with Grails, the `org.grails.plugins:mail` plugin will help.

Specific recommendations for how best do this depend on more info, but you can definitely do this with Groovy.